# Having issues with Remix Solidity contract for the unit256 value

Tags: solidity, remix

uint256 public swapThreshold = 5 * 10**5 * (10 ** _decimals)

I am trying to figure out what the actual true number of this is so I can input it into my Cronos smart contract, the router is pushing out our USDC rewards at $0.00000007 and people are asking why they are not getting rewards when we are at 8% rewards....The LP pair is awesome works as it should but some reason the main contract side isn't working as it should....
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by actual true number?

Comment: Would it be 500,000 that I would input into cronos org.....In the beginning things were changed and trying to fix the rewards for hodling UCRO..

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear.

If you are asking what is the decimal value of

```
uint256 public swapThreshold = 5 * 10**5 * (10 ** _decimals)
```

Start with `500 000` and add as many zeros as your `_decimals` value to the end.

Eg. if your `_decimals` is 4, then the `swapThreshold` is `5 000 000 000`

Comment: On cronos . org under write contract when it ask for swapnliquify=true swapthreshhold amount=??? which is what i need to know what the 5* 10**5 * (10 ** _decimals) is and swaplimit amount